# Processing MERGE request response failed: The reference to entity "token" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: eclipse, svn, jenkins

I'm attempting to POST to Jenkins using wget in my post-commit.

- The buildByToken in the URL reflects the use of the Build Authorization Token Root Plugin for Jenkins.
- I'm using Eclipse/Kepler with Subversive

Post-commit script:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

if svnlook dirs-changed -r "$REV" "$REPOS" | grep -qEe '^trunk/'; then
  wget "http://my.domain.com:8080/buildByToken/buildWithParameters?job=APS-RemoteServerAction&token=abcdef&amp;ACTION=deploy&amp;ASSET_NAME=POST-COMMIT-TEST&amp;DEPLOY_ENV=DEV&amp;REVISION=$REV
fi
```

Error:

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Processing MERGE request response failed: The reference to entity "token" must end with the ';' delimiter. (/svn/post-commit-tests/trunk) 
svn: E175002: MERGE request failed on '/svn/post-commit-tests/trunk'
```

My error message brought up other posts about XML errors and escaping the &.

So, I tried modifying the wget call:

- using `&amp;` instead of &
- I've tried various combinations of individually double quoting post-data and the URL
- I've tried escaping the & with the back slash

The tricks above didn't solve the issue at hand.